# Adobe Flex Mobile Embed Audio m3u, ram or asx

Tags: apache-flex, audio, mobile, embed

Is it possible to embed & play either m3u, ram or asx audio streams in Adobe Flex Mobile?

I have an audio feed that I would like to make available in my application but am having problems connecting to it.  Thanks.

JH

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundLoaderContext;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var s:Sound = new Sound();
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest('url to my stream');
var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(8000, true);
s.load(req, context);
s.play();
```

Comment: I'm confused exactly what you mean.  How do you embed something that is streaming.

Comment: I just want to play the stream. Embed the audio file.

Comment: Aren't those two contradictory things?  A stream, by definition comes from the server.  An embedded asset, but definition, does not. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I have a file that connects to a remote stream when opened. I would like to play that file.

Comment: After a little research, I found that the m3u/asx files are just text files with information about the stream that the player uses to connect.  I have edited the question above to include the source that i am trying to get to work.  It works fine in my emulator and on Android however does not work on iOS.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I didn't realize that was unknown to you.  Hopefully my questions make a little more sense now.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any previous experience with audio/video streaming.  Any idea why this wouldn't work in iOS?  Stream I would like to connect to: http://relay.radioreference.com:80/295359268

Comment: I don't know; I know some things are limited via iOS. On mobile I Generally don't recommend trying to get the app to play anything.  Just launch a URL and let the OS handle it.

Comment: That works, thanks for your help.  What are your final thoughts on embedding this page into a stageWebView?  It appears to load and play without issue from there.  That would keep it within my application.

Comment: I have no other thoughts; that is a "Business decision" you have to make based on business rules.  I'm pragmatic about such things.  If it works; then it works.